# SQL to return single row per group

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a query that returns a single row or record per group. 
For example I have a table 'employee' with columns:

```
id, name, type

1, John, full-time
2, Mike, full-time
3, Alex, part-time
4, Jerry, part-time
```

I need to return something like

```
1, John, full-time
4, Alex, part-time
```

Thanks

Comment: `GROUP BY type` after the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use "group by" in your SQL request.

Let's say you have a table EMPLOYEES :

```
ID | NAME    | TYPE
1  | 'John'  | 'full-time'
2  | 'Mike'  | 'full-time'
3  | 'Alex'  | 'part-time'
4  | 'Jerry' | 'part-time'
```

You can run:

```
Select * from employees group by type
```

This would return:

```
ID | NAME | TYPE
1  | John | full-time
3  | Alex | part-time
```

**Note** with this approach the returned Name and Id are not choosen or certain.
To have a specific Id (say the biggest) in the returned result, prefer the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(id) AS id, type
    FROM employees
    GROUP BY type
) e2
ON e.id = e2.id
AND e.type = e2.type;
```

Comment: Do realize that this can return unexpected results for the `id` and the `name` column?

Comment: @bluefeet agree, not sure if it was a concern in the question

Comment: Hm... I always thought you can only specify aggregate functions or columns by which you perform grouping in select.

Comment: Never ever ever ever ever `GROUP BY` like this...you're just asking for trouble, and MySQL is the only implementation that will even allow it to parse.

Comment: @StasS - for SQL standards then pretty much true. MySQL will cope and not complain but the contents of the non GROUP BY columns which are not from an aggregate column will be from an undefined row. Hence in thos question for full-time whether the id is 1 or 2, and whether the name is John or Mike is not certain

Comment: I have explained this query here: https://gist.github.com/AayushSameerShah/63d9c18280147a150460f83cf77e3983 by showing intermediate tables.

Answer (score 8):

You will want to apply an aggregate function with a GROUP BY:

```
select min(id) id, 
  min(name) name,
  type
from yourtable
group by type;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11243/1).

The above works if you don't care what id/name is returned for each type. If you do then you can use:

```
select t1.id,
  t1.name,
  t1.type
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select min(id) id, type
  from yourtable 
  group by type
) t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
  and t1.type = t2.type
```

or

```
select t1.id,
  t1.name,
  t1.type
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select min(name) name, type
  from yourtable 
  group by type
) t2
  on t1.name = t2.name
  and t1.type = t2.type;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11243/8)

Comment: bf. You've got a rep of 79.2k, which leads me to conclude you must be smoking something!??!

Comment: @Strawberry Care to explain?

Comment: @Strawberry The OP did not specify that they want the id that is associated with the name. Their desired result shows 4 with Alex.  But your concern is noted and I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should pick a particular record for each type, then join back to get the rest of the fields like this:-

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.type
FROM employee a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT type, MIN(id) AS id
    FROM employee
    GROUP BY type
) Sub1
ON a.id = Sub1.id
AND a.type = Sub1.type
```

While you could do something like the following

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.type
FROM employee a
GROUP BY type
```

this can have side effects. The rows that the id and name come from may not be the row (currently they probably will), and which row MySQL choses to take those fields from is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Did You try this?

```
SELECT * FROM employee GROUP BY group;
```

Comment: this should be comment not answer

Answer (score -1):

```
Select * from Employee
Group by Type
```